# Add UIButton to UITableView programmatically but the button doesn't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'd like to add a button above table view, not scrolled with the table view. But the button doesn't show. Any ideas?

```
UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"refresh"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGRect applicationFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
CGFloat screenWidth = CGRectGetWidth(applicationFrame);
CGFloat screenHeight = CGRectGetHeight(applicationFrame);
CGFloat buttonWidth = 40.0f;
CGFloat buttonHeight = 40.0f;
CGFloat spacing = 10.0f;
CGFloat buttonX = screenWidth - buttonWidth - spacing;
CGFloat buttonY = screenHeight - buttonHeight - spacing;
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
refreshButton.frame = buttonFrame;
[refreshButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(clickRefreshButton)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:refreshButton];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add the button to table header view

Comment: Still nothing appears :(

Comment: if you add butotn to table header view, it will be scrolled along to the tableview.

Comment: THe code you posted doesnt add the button to table view. It adds button to view, which is coverred by table view.

Comment: I checked by view hierarchy but there is no button, not covered by table view. Also if I add it as a subview to table view, it won't show either.

Comment: where exactly do you call the button add code ?

Comment: In the viewDidLoad of the tableViewController.

Comment: try to call it in view will appear/viw did appear and check the view debugger

Comment: I tried add the button in both methods, but there isn't a uibutton in debug navigator when I use view debugger.

Comment: may be the butotn frame is wrong. Put a breakpoint on the line addSubview, and try to log the butotn frame.

Comment: Sadly I've checked the frame but there's nothing wrong orz

Comment: What is the frame value ?

Comment: {{364, 686}, {40, 40}}

Comment: And the screen frame value is {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a `UITableViewController`. The reason: the `view` property of the view controller **is** the table view, so you cannot add anything above it.

The way to do this is to use a plain `UIViewController` and add your button and a `UITableView` as subviews (better in Interface Builder than in code, BTW).

In order to make the table view work as expected you have to add

- an outlet for the table view
- adopt the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols
- as in a `UITableViewController`, implement at least the necessary datasource methods

Comment: Well I wonder why I can't add a uibutton onto a uitableview since uitableview inherits from uiview?

Comment: But it also inherits from `UIScrollView` so things get complicated. Subviews of scroll views are treated differently (i.e., they scroll ;-)).

Comment: So if I use UIViewController and add a button to self.view then it means the tableView and the button are all subviews of self.view, and they are parallel?

Comment: Okay. Let me try it.

Comment: I've set tableView in a UIViewController in storyboard and set all outlets(including tableview, datasource, delegate), also let the viewController adopt the UITableViewDataSource and the UITableViewDelegate protocols, and implement the necessary methods as well. But nothing shows when I run the app. It turns out that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are not executed at all. Do you know why?

Comment: So how should I set it?

Comment: `tableView.dataSource = self
`